# summing vectors jump one element; alternative for loop in r

Tags: r

I'm sure this is really simple, but I can't get my head around how to vectorise this for loop

```
x <- 1:3
y <- 11:13

z <- x[1]
for(i in 2:length(x)){
    tem <- x[i] + y[i-1]
    z <- c(z, tem)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this?

```
> c(x[1],tail(x,-1) + head(y,-1))
[1]  1 13 15
```